# Boardcast receiver not working in Android for Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, broadcastreceiver, android-location

Below is the code i am using to use broadcast receiver :-
What i am trying to achieve is 
1) When user turn on/off location when app is in background it should get broadcasted. I had put the debugger but it is not getting called when application move to background.
2) Fetch updated location when app is in background.

**In MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery";
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
            .setMethodCallHandler(
                    (call, result) -> {
                        GpsLocationReceiver networkstatusreceiver = new GpsLocationReceiver();
                        IntentFilter intent=new IntentFilter ();
                        intent.addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED");
                        registerReceiver(networkstatusreceiver,intent);

                      // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                      // TODO
                    }
            );
  }
}
```

**GpsLocationReceiver.java**

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            Log.d("PROVIDERS_CHANGED null", "PROVIDERS_CHANGED null");

        }
    }
}
```

Added below in `manifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

    <receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```